# TypeScript: how to remap interface on 1 element while destructuring object?

Tags: typescript

When destructuring an object in typescript 3.4 I can do this:

```
interface IObject {
    ...
}
const {loading, data, error}:{loading: boolean, data: IObject, error: string} = myResponseObject;
```

However, in my case I have already defined a response object so I want to specify the exact response type like this:

```
interface IResponse {
    loading: boolean;
    data: any;
    error: string;
}
interface IObject {
    ...
}
const {loading, data, error}:{data: IObject} = myResponseObject;
```

Basically, I want to take take my `myResponseObject.data: any` type and transform it into  `myResponseObject.data: IObject` type while destructuring, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `data`'s type as generic, then you'll be able to specify its type on destructuring:

```
interface IResponse<T = any> {
  loading: boolean;
  data: T;
  error: string;
}
interface IObject {
}

declare const myResponseObject: IResponse;
const { loading, data, error }: IResponse<IObject> = myResponseObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with casting. You'd extend `IResponse` to have a stricter definition of `data`:

```
interface IResponseWithTypedData extends IResponse {
 data: IObject;
}
```

Then when you de-structure, apply the cast.

```
const { data } = myResponseObject as IResponseWithTypedData;
```

Comment: This is a good answer and definitely answers the questions I asked, but I marked @aleksey as the answer this time since using a Generic answers the questions beyond the question i asked